# Make Fread run until there's not enough bytes

Tags: c

So what im asking is how to make fread function loop until left with not enough bytes to look at.
Is this okay? :
while(fread(buffer, 512, 1, image)) == 512 );

Comment: Please read e.g. [this `fread` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread). Pay close attention to the `count` and `size` variables, and what the function returns.

Comment: `fread` returns the number of _elements_. So, you for your loop to work, you have to reverse the arguments: `while (fread(buffer, 1, 512, image)) == 512)` That is the usual/best way to do this (e.g. for the `cs50` image split problem ;-). The other way would be: `while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, image)) == 1)`

Comment: From the man page: "On  success,  `fread()`  and  `fwrite()` return the number of _items_ read or written. This number equals the number of bytes transferred _only_ when `size` is 1." Remember, the prototype is: `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);`

Comment: ...and it's best to store the amount read in a variable, so you know how much to process of the final block.